# How does one group words together to show that they are the same object in the sentence?

Tags: punctuation

I have encountered situations where a sentence can be rather ambiguous because it can be read in 2 different ways.

In the sentence "The large blue car is very slow.", how do I show that "The large blue car" is one thing and "very slow" another seperate thing? (this sentence is a rather bad example, as it is very clear what words are grouped together without the need of additional puntualtion, but I cannot think of a good example where grouping words together would be needed off the top of my head.)

The way I would usually do it is to use square brackets: "[The large blue car] is [very slow]." but I dont know if this is the correct way of doing it. I was wondering if there is an official way to do this.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. I don't see how your sentence can be read in two different ways. Also, if you claim that your sentence is a bad example, try to find a better one to make your question clearer.

Comment: ""Very slow" is called a subjective predicative complement of "be", since it refers to the subject "the large blue car". Is that what you mean?

Comment: Ok I think I have been unclear. I am very bad at examples so I wont be able to find a good one. The example I gave doesn't demonstrate a sentence that can be read in two ways. To clarify: I do not mean parts of a sentence like subject, direct object etc, I instead mean packing several words together to show that they are supposed to be one 'variable' (for lack of a better term). Like in the sentence: "The car was very broken but drivable." I want to pack "broken but drivable" as one 'variable'. "The car was very [broken but drivable]." rather than "The car was very [broken] but [drivable]."

Comment: It's fine to call "broken but drivable" a syntactic unit, more precisely a coordination of two adjectives. This would give "The car was [broken but drivable].